# What is the best approach for reassigning a variable if it equals one of say 50 known values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The main aim is of my code is:

If variable x is equal to a value then I want to reassign x with a different value. eg if x = a then reassign x to = 1 but if x = b then reassign x to = 2. I have around 50 values I want to compare x against to see if it equals one of them.

With my basic Python knowledge, I can see one way to achieve this by using 50 if statements in a function, haha but surely there must be a much simpler more code efficient way?

```
def testfunc(x):
    if x == "url1":
        x = 'company1'

    if x == 'url2':
        x = 'company2'

    if x == 'url3':
        x = 'company3'

    # plus 47 more 'if' statements
    return x
```

I was thinking using a dictionary may be better where if x = key then make x = value, would this be a better approach? Or is there an even better way?

Some direction on the best way to code this or a simple example to get me started would be much appreciated.

Comment: you could just do, `x = x.replace('url', 'company')`, if the numbers are symmetrical.

Comment: At least use elif in case like this but @101 has right with dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a dictionary would work well.

```
def testfunc(x):
    d = {
        'url1': 'company1',
        'url2': 'company2'
    }
    return d[x]

x = 'url1'
x = testfunc(x)
print(x)    # 'company1'
```

Comment: this will give a KeyError if `x not in d`. If this is not wanted behaviour, you can use `d.get(x, x)` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get))